# Override ido-completion-map to change window target

Tags: completion, ido, ido-find-file

Sometimes I open `ido-find-file` or `ido-switch-buffer` but when I find the file I want to open, I realize I want to open it in `other-window`. I have key bindings for `ido-find-file-other-window` and others, but I would like the option to open the selected ido candidate in `other-window` as a persistent option in `ido-completion-map` (bound to `s-<return>`). Is this possible?

Comment: You can probably make your own command using ido-read-file-name. Similar to the updated answer here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9450/780

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out a pattern that worked by advising `ido-read-internal` with an empty dynamic variable that would get set with a custom command bound to `ido-common-completion-map`.

I published the idea as a package called [`ido-exit-target`](https://github.com/waymondo/ido-exit-target), but here's the pattern that solves my question:

```
(eval-when-compile
  (defvar ido-exit-target--target))

(defun ido-exit-target-other-window ()
  "Select the current `ido' item for `other-window'. It will create one if it doesn't exist."
  (interactive)
  (setq ido-exit-target--target 'other-window)
  (ido-exit-minibuffer))

(defun ido-exit-target--switch-to-target (orig-fun &rest args)
  "Advise `ido-read-internal' on where to view the chosen selection."
  (let* (ido-exit-target--target
         (res (apply orig-fun args)))
    (when (equal ido-exit-target--target 'other-window)
      (switch-to-buffer-other-window nil))
    res))

(advice-add 'ido-read-internal :around #'ido-exit-target--switch-to-target)

(define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<s-return>") #'ido-exit-target-other-window)
```