# Go to window by buffername

Tags: buffers, window, navigation

I would like to be able to switch to an open window by typing the name of the buffer which is displayed in it.
It would be something like C-x b which opens the selected buffer only if it is not opened in another windows and in that case the focus switch to that window.

Comment: There is no need for anything fancy, just `(select-window (get-buffer-window "NAME-OF-BUFFER"))` and/or the optional second argument ALL-FRAMES.  Perhaps consider adding a test for whether the window exists (i.e., live) so as to avoid throwing an error if you make a typographical error in the buffer-name.

Answer (score 2):

For a slightly different approach, you can install the https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window package (available from melpa) and bind `ace-window` to some key sequence. When you invoke it, it gives each window a letter or number, which you can type to select. If you turn on `ace-window-display-mode` this letter is also added to the mode line so you can see it in advance.

The answer to [Defining the window pointed by "other-window"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/991/defining-the-window-pointed-by-other-window?rq=1) has a screencast showing it in action.

The package has extra features, for example if invoked with one universal argument it swaps the current window with the target window.

The https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window/wiki has an extended example, with scrolling other windows, `winner-mode` to save and restore window configurations and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) to select a buffer, [`get-buffer-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers-and-Windows.html) to find the window showing that buffer, and [`select-window`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Selecting-Windows.html) to switch to that window:

```
(defun open-window-by-buffer (buffer)
  (interactive "bBuffer: ")
  (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer) nil))
```

I love `ido-mode` for selecting things like open buffers, so here's a solution using that:

```
(defun open-window-by-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buffer
         (ido-completing-read
          "Buffer: "
          (mapcar 'buffer-name (buffer-list)))))
    (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer) nil)))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can use command `icicle-select-window`, bound to **`C-0 C-x o`** to [trip among windows](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Tripping) using
their buffer names.

More generally, **`C-x o`** trips among windows or frames, as follows (`C-h k C-x o`):

> **`C-x o`** runs the command **`icicle-other-window-or-frame`**
>          which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in [`icicles-cmd1.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/icicles-cmd1.el).
>
> `(icicle-other-window-or-frame ARG)`
>
> Select a window or frame, by name or by order.
>
> This command combines Emacs commands `other-window` and `other-frame`,
>       together with Icicles commands **`icicle-select-window`**,
>       **`icicle-select-frame`**, and **`icicle-choose-window-for-buffer-display`**.
>
> Use the *prefix argument* to choose the behavior, as follows:
>
> - With *no* prefix arg or a *non-zero* numeric prefix arg:
>       If the selected frame has multiple windows, then this is
>       `other-window`.  Otherwise, it is `other-frame`.
> - With a *zero* prefix arg (e.g. **`C-0`**):
>       If the selected frame has multiple windows, then this is
>       `icicle-select-window` with windows in the frame as candidates.
>       Otherwise (single-window frame), this is `icicle-select-frame`.
> - With plain **`C-u`**:
>       If the selected frame has multiple windows, then this is
>       `icicle-select-window` with windows from all visible frames as
>       candidates.  Otherwise, this is `icicle-select-frame`.
> - With plain **`C-u C-u`**:
>       Same as `icicle-select-window` with a negative prefix arg: Select a
>       window from any frame, including iconified and invisible frames.
> - With plain **`C-u C-u C-u`**:
>       This is `icicle-choose-window-for-buffer-display`, with windows from
>       all frames (i.e., iconified and invisible) frames as candidates.
>
> If you use library [`oneonone.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/oneonone.el) with a *standalone minibuffer* frame,
>       and if option `1on1-remap-other-frame-command-flag` is non-nil, then
>       frame selection can include the standalone minibuffer frame.
>
> By default, Icicle mode remaps all key sequences that are normally
>       bound to `other-window` to `icicle-other-window-or-frame`.  If you do
>       not want this remapping, then customize option
>       `icicle-top-level-key-bindings`.